# Using Power Desktop with an Azure VM and Enterprise Gateway

Tags: sql-server, azure, powerbi

I am developing a report in PowerBI Desktop based on data hosted in an Azure SQL Server VM. 
When publishing a report, I get the below error:

> Publishing succeeded, but the published report cannot connect to the
>   data source because we were unable to find a gateway. Please install
>   and configure an enterprise gateway

I believe this is because the enterprise gateway is installed locally on my azure VM, however I'm accessing it from my desktop by going over the web and through the firewall. Therefore I believe the issue is that my pc acceses the machine at

> mymachine.cloudapp.net

Whilst the enterprise gateway knows the machine as

> netbios-name

Is there any way that I can upload a desktop report to powerBI web using this configuration? The other solution would be to get the machine and sql server to identify itself as "mymachine.cloudapp.net" so that I can use this as the name to connect to through the enterprise gateway, but I'm not sure how to do that (adding the alias to SQL Server isn't enough).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but I've got a work around.

Open the server and edit your hosts file and add the following line:

> 127.0.0.1       mymachine.cloudapp.net

Make sure that mymachine.cloudapp.net has been configured in SQL Server as an alias.

In PowerBI, add a new enterprise gateway data source, this time, use mymachine.cloudapp.net to connect rather than netbios-name. You will need to use SQL Authentication to connect.

Obviously connecting PowerBI to an Azure VM in this way is not ideal, as it could potentially be unencrypted, but this works around the issue of different host names between PowerBI Desktop and Web.